# ExtJs: best practices to handle images saving/retrieval

Tags: image, extjs, extjs4

We are developing a web application with ExtJs 4 and Microsoft RIA services + MS SQL Server on the back end. Currently some of the records we store in the DB have attached images to them. Images are stored in binary format in the DB.

What would be the best approach to:

- Display them within ExtJs framework
- Allow users to upload images via same ExtJs front end

I looked through ExtJs docs and looks like we would need to provide images as basically individual files and use simple `img` tag for that. Is that correct assumption? Are there other approaches to render images from binary data (which we currently serve via JSON endpoints)?

Is there samples handy for image upload logic?

Comment: Rendering binary adds overhead. Store the images in a folder and store the filenames in your DB.

Comment: I understand. But it's a legacy code that I'm not trying to change yet, and also images are relatively small and don't take much space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS will give you a framework for getting the images via forms to your back end, but what you do with the images from there is completely ExtJS independent. Displaying them within ExtJS is completely independent of the back end logic as well. It's just a matter of finding a way to pipe the data up to the browser just as you would if you were writing a normal HTML page.

I'll take the answer one step further and mention: Storing images in the database is generally a bad idea. At least, storing them in a relational database is generally not a great plan. If I couldn't use a database like Riak (or Amazon's S3) for storing the images, I would probably follow Diodeus' comment and put them directly in the filesystem.